# percentage in javascript and then reverse from percentage to targetValue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate `percentageDifference` in one place with `baseValue + targetValue`. Then in a different place, I am calculating the `targetValue` with the `baseValue + percentageDifference`. The issue I get is, the first calculation give me the `percentageDifference` and when I use it for the second calculation I get a different `targetValue` than the first calculation.

How do I make sure to use the same 3 values in all calculations all the time?

```
// Calculate targetValue

let baseValue = 50.8998;
let percentageDifference = 0.01;
let change = (percentageDifference / 100.0) * baseValue;
let targetValue = baseValue + change;

// Calculate percentageDifference

let baseValue = 50.8998;
let targetValue = 55.7878;
let percent = Math.abs(baseValue - targetValue) / baseValue;
let percentageDifference = percent * 100.0;
```

Comment: Are you certain that this is correct? `percentageDifference / 100.0`
What is the unit of `percentageDifference`?

Comment: My suggestion; stop multiplying and dividing by 100. Just keep the number as is. If you need to display the value, create a new variable *just for display* that you multiply by 100.

Answer (score 0):

Works ok, removed Math.abs, simplified numbers

```js
//calculate percentageDifference
let baseValue = 50;
let targetValue = 75;
let percent = (targetValue - baseValue) / baseValue;
let percentageDifference = percent * 100;
console.log('percentageDifference', percentageDifference, '. From', baseValue, 'to', targetValue)

//calculate targetValue
let baseValue1 = 50;
let percentageDifference1 = 50;
let change1 = (percentageDifference1 / 100) * baseValue1;
let targetValue1 = baseValue1 + change1;
console.log('targetValue', targetValue1)
```

Comment: thanks so much @Medet Tleukabiluly. This was helpful.